# Paypal Pro - how to debug issue with paypal API

Tags: paypal

I noted than the invoice generated by Paypal Pro doesn't contain the details about the payment: the entire *'Description'* column is empty.

How to debug the issue ? Where the these info are passed to the Paypal API ?

Comment: copy Mage/core/paypal module in local folder and from hear you can debug

Answer (score 4):

You can turn on debugging mode for the payment method.

Look in **System->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->Payments Pro->Advanced Settings**

This will log all requests and responses to your var/log directory.

Comment: Note that the debug output is logged to a `payment.log` file within `var/log`